# Implement Posted Form from NodeJS into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

I recently switched from starting to learn PHP to NodeJS since I have more knowledge in JS. My question is how do I display posted form data into a HTML File?

*server.js*

```
const app = require('express')(),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'html/index.html')));
app.post('/student', (req, res) => res.send(req.body.user.name));

app.listen(3000, (req, res) => console.log('Listening on port 3000.'));
```

*html/index.html*

```
<body>
    <form method='post' action='post'>
        <input type='text' name = 'user[name]'>
        <input type='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
</body>
```

However in the **post** method, I want to send a HTML file, instead of `req.body.user.name` which I could obviously do like I did on the home page (`/`), I want to be able to include some variables into the new HTML File, maybe something looking along the lines of:

```
<body>
    <h1><? req.body.user.name + 's page. ?></h1>
    <!-- rest of code -->
</body>
```

Comment: Are you looking for templating? https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `ejs` template for this purpose and it is very easy to use.

First of all, download ejs with `npm install ejs -s` and create a `views` folder inside your main directory. Inside that folder, create a normal html file but this time with an extension of `.ejs`.

```
App Directory

-views/myFile.ejs
      /post.ejs
-html/index.html
-server.js
```

Now let's go to your server.js file. You need to use `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')` to run ejs. When you do `res.render()` you don't have specify the path because the program already looks for `views/` folder in the main directory.

```
const app = require('express')(),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('myFile.ejs', {username: 'myUser'}));
app.post('/student', function(req, res){
    var username = req.body.user.name;
    res.render('post.ejs', {user: username});
});

app.listen(3000, (req, res) => console.log('Listening on port 3000.'));
```

This is our sample `myFile.ejs`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><%=username%></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is our sample `post.ejs`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><%=user%></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some template engine, there is tutorial on express page https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html.
There is always possibility that you can write your own module for handling this.

You can also install express generator

```
npm install express-generator -g
```

then call:

```
express
```

Thanks to this you will setup express project with jade as template engine(it is default), it should allow you to progress further.